# How to get particular notification count number

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have three categories of `UILocalNotification` - every Sunday, Monday and Saturday Notifications.

How to get the particular notification i.e Monday triggered count number. 
I have a notification `UILocalNotification` (not remote or push notification).

How do I get count of Monday Notification which are triggered within two Months?

Note: There is no scope of push or remote notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to manually manage this, the way I would suggest doing it is by utilising the `didReceiveLocalNotification` method of your AppDelegate. Implement this and then check the `fireDate` property of your `UILocalNotificationObject`. You can parse this to be a day of the week by using the following code:

```
int dayOfWeek = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:notification.fireDate];
```

You can then store increment this value in the `NSUserDefaults` based on the number you have. 1 will be Monday, 2 Tuesday etc...

```
long dayOfWeek = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:notification.fireDate];
long currentCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"weekdayNotificationCount_%ld", dayOfWeek]];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:currentCount + 1 forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"weekdayNotificationCount_%ld", dayOfWeek]];
```

That way you will always have a running total stored in your `NSUserDefaults` and this will only disappear if the app is deleted.

Comment: didReceiveLocalNotification is trigger when i tap on received notification message.  If I did not open the notification then didReceiveLocalNotification will not work and count will be mismatch.

Comment: Hmm in that case I think you might be stuck. You can do it with remote notifications for sure but you have already said you have no scope for this.

Comment: you are correct I do not have scope for push notification for that,  is there any method that trigger once i received the notification bill rings?

Comment: Unfortunately not in the case of local notifications, to get the functionality you are looking for you would have to implement remote notifications. This doesn't mean you have to write a backend though as services like Firebase do it for you, for free.

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing it for free!  Which forcefully need to implemented which we do not required at this stage for the application.